# Add column to list, which shows item-level permissions

Tags: list, permissions, lookup-column, item-level-permissions

Is there a way to create a column, that shows all groups and users (SP groups and AD) that can view this item? I'm not talking about having column-level permissions as this was the only thing I found as I was searching. I just want to easily see, who can view each item, without going through the menu (details -> permissions). [This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/245864/103498) seems to go in a similar direction, but I feel like it's not the same problem.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: The cloud version (Microsoft 365)

Comment: Is this such an odd thing to want Sharepoint to show? I'm new to Sharepoint thought I'm just overlooking an obvious option.

Comment: I'm not sure but unique permissions on individual list items is generally bad practice and certainly not ideal.